# Problem creating a child class using an alternative constructor of parent

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization, parent-child

I have a class that creates blocks in a 2d board. I defined it so it does so given their height, length and location on the board but also made an alternative constructor to create blocks by passing its coordinates in the board.

```
class Block:
    """ Create a block of given height and length in a starting location."""

    def __init__(self, name: str, h: int, l: int, location: Tuple[int,int]):
        self.name = name
        self.coords = [tuple_sum(t1=location, t2=(i//l , i%l)) for i in range(h*l)]
        # tuple_sum does (a, b)+(c, d) -> (a+c, b+d)        

    @classmethod
    def from_coords(cls, name: str, coords: List[Tuple]):
        block = cls.__new__(cls)
        block.name = name
        block.coords = coords
        return block

    ...

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Name: {self.name}\nCoords: {self.coords}'
```

I'm trying to create a child class for the blank spaces in the board. I thought that using the from_coords constructor would do everything but for some reason I don't understand the created elements are not initialized, i.e don't have name or coords attributes.

```
class SpacesBlock(Block):
    """ Make a block of spaces from a list of coordenates """
    def __init__(self, coords):
        super().from_coords("  ",coords)

    ...

spaces = SpacesBlock([(0,0),(0,1)])
print(spaces)

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
\block.py in <module>
      space = SpacesBlock([(0,0),(0,1)])
----> print(spaces)

AttributeError: 'SpacesBlock' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I thought it was the from_coords constructor but it works fine

```
a = Block.from_coords("A",[(0,0),(1,0)])
print(a)

Name: A
Coords: [(0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

I know I can just define the name and coords in the init of SpacesBlock and everything is fine but I am very curious about why it doesn't work as I thought it would. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from_coords` is **not a constructor**. It is a *factory method*.

`__init__` actually initializes an already-existing (i.e., allocated) object. Because it's an ordinary method, receiving a `self` parameter, it is able to do so. A `classmethod` cannot initialize an already-existing object unless you provide it one explicitly.

What happens in your code is that `super().from_coords("  ",coords)` creates a *separate* instance of `Block`, which is then discarded. The `self` instance of `SpacesBlock` doesn't get its `.name` set; that happened to the other instance.

The point of `@classmethod` (as opposed to `@staticmethod`) is that, because you receive a parameter which is *the class*, it can still behave polymorphically even though you don't have an object instance. (As you've found, you can use this to make `__new__` work polymorphically.)

Your factory method can already behave polymorphically: `SpacesBlock.from_coords` will call the method, and pass `SpacesBlock` as the `cls`, so that `cls.__new__` creates a new `SpacesBlock` instance. However, `__init__` doesn't get called this way; and with your current organizational structure, it's not clear how you would call it or what you would pass.

Real justified uses for `__new__` are rare.

The normal way to use factory methods is to have them call `__init__`, by *determining parameters to use* for the `__init__` call. In your case, a list of coordinates could be whatever arbitrary positions; but a width, height and location give you a way to specify multiple coordinates. It would be easier, therefore, to use the actual constructor for the list-of-coordinates approach to construction.

With that setup, the code looks something like:

```py
class Block:
    def __init__(self, name: str, coords: List[Tuple]):
        self.name = name
        self.coords = coords

    @classmethod
    def from_grid(cls, name: str, h: int, l: int, location: Tuple[int,int]):
        coords = [tuple_sum(location, (i//l , i%l)) for i in range(h*l)]
        return cls(name, coords)


class SpacesBlock(Block):
    pass # thus far, doesn't actually do anything different
```

The important thing to note here is that `from_grid` can be used for either class now. `Block.from_grid` creates a `Block` instance, and `SpacesBlock.from_grid` creates a `SpacesBlock` instance - in either case, using the (height, length, location) approach. To create either class from a list of coordinates directly, simply call the constructor directly.

Comment: Just thought I should also mention that it is perfectly fine and occasionally useful to use `@classmethod`s for *non-* factory methods, too. The only thing that's special here is creating and returning an instance of `cls`.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute

```
spaces = SpacesBlock([(0,0),(0,1)])
```

you create an instance `SpaceBlock`. Then `__init__` runs to initialize this object. The problem is, that the `__init__` function in `SpaceBlock` does not modify the instance you have just created. Instead, it creates and instantiates another object. This new object is not used for anything, and the one you originally created it left without any modifications, in particular without the `name` and `coords` attributes.

You could fix it by modifying `__init__` e.g. as follows:

```
def __init__(self, coords):
    x = super().from_coords("  ",coords)
    self.name  = x.name
    self.coords = x.coords
```

but this would be an unnecessarily convoluted code.